# Error: Use of unassigned local variable when passing reference for output

Tags: c#, pass-by-reference

I just got this error when trying to use a function parameter for a return value.
I could only find answers to related issues but not this one.

Example:

```
void someNumber(int foo)
{
  foo = 3;
}

int bar;
someNumber(bar);
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: You're not using *any* kind of pass-by-reference here. Did you mean to make `foo` a `ref` parameter?

Comment: Also, if you want to return a value, why don't you just *use the return value*? It's very rare to want to use pass by reference for a `void` method.

Comment: For more information about parameter passing in C#, please read http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html

Comment: You could have just used a return state in your method and obtain the value that way.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, damn oversimplified. The original function used a List<String> so no ref was necessary. Also, the version that caused the problem used more than one return value.

Comment: @CorporalTouchy: I strongly suspect you've misunderstood the meaning of `ref`. Please read the link I provided a few comments further up. Just because a parameter type is a reference type does *not* imply `ref`.

Comment: Apparently I had misunderstood several things, which makes it a good thing I asked this question but it's too unstructured and should probably be deleted now.

Comment: bar is not initialized: int bar = 0;

Comment: Haha, "This difference is absolutely crucial to understanding parameter passing in C#, and is why I believe it is highly confusing to say that objects are passed by reference by default instead of the correct statement that object references are passed by value by default." I have been told exactly that, that objects are passed by reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out C# is a bit weird in this respect but better weird than C/C++. :)

If you pass a reference only for the output value you have to make that explicit in this way:

```
void someNumber(out int foo)
{
  foo = 3;
}

int bar;
someNumber(out bar);
```

So while you still have an output parameter in the input parameter list (at least that's what it is in my head) at least it is now blatantly obvious.

Note that it is now an error NOT to assign to foo in the body of someNumber. It's kind of like an anti-const, which would obviously have been a much cooler keyword. ;)

Comment: In what way is C# "a bit weird" here? Its rules are pretty straightforward and consistent, IMO. (Note that the OP is using straight pass-by-value - there's no `out` *or* `ref` modifier on the parameter.)

Comment: Additionally, talking about "passing a reference" is very confusing; you're passing a variable by reference, which isn't the same thing as passing a reference (e.g. the value of a `string` variable) by value.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference? I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: It's weird to use a parameter for the return value. There is now a "return value" and a list of additional return values that are in the parameter list with an "out" keyword.

Comment: Read the document I linked to and you'll see what I mean about the difference. And yes, it's weird to use a parameter for an output value - so try not to do it. (That's one reason your initial example was bad.)

Answer (score 0):

```
void someNumber(int foo)
{
  foo = 3;
}

int bar;
someNumber(bar);
```

foo is an input parameter, so you can't change its value..

Because use return function.

```
int someNumber(int foo)
{
    foo=3;
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: You *can* change the value of `foo` in the first snippet - it just won't make any difference to the original argument.